# Creating a hidden iframe in a chrome extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create an iframe on the background.html page in a google-chrome extension and have it make the request to the website? I am not sure how exactly the extension works. Does chrome automatically ignore all display tags or will it run it invisibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the background page of an extension is never displayed, but it should "run" as expected (e.g. `src` attribute of an `img` tag will cause the image data to be fetched). I'm new to implementing extensions, but [the architecture overview](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html#arch) seems to imply this, as do the samples I've seen.

You can click on the link to background.html in the extensions control panel and inspect the source/dom/etc.

Answer (score 6):

It will load the iframe all right, but I don't think it's possible to read anything out of an iframe due to same-origin restrictions. For example, this background script fails:

```
<body>
<script>
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
iframe.onload = function() {
  console.log(iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML);
};
</script>
```

with error: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.google.com/ from frame with URL chrome-extension://elbpnmnjddamdmjmdnmhankaimaldhmf/background.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: Because upon installing the extension you can request permission to those other domains (ie: google.com or other) chrome extensions aren't restricted to cross-origin requests as a normal page would be. The caviot is that you have to request the permission from the user, either upon installation or subsequently.

Comment: @aaronfrost, yes, you can request permission to e.g. `"http://www.google.com/*"`, but at the moment it only applies to cross-origin XMLHttpRequests, injecting content scripts, and reading cookies. It does not apply to reading an iframe within a background page. Perhaps you could file a feature request. Or perhaps it's the same issue as http://crbug.com/20773

Answer (score 0):

After testing myself: Apparently google-chrome does run iframes. It just wont display them.