# Get html of dynamic AngularJS ng-view code via XHR

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a chrome extension that needs to parse several pages on a domain.  I normally do this by using a [background XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699615/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-using-background-pages) and then send the response into jquery.

> $(xhr.responseText)

However, the response from the XHR does not contain all the HTML and JQuery is not processing the dynamic content.  The pages use AngluarJS ng-view and that portion of the page is not populating.  The data can not be queried directly as it appears to be proxied.

Simplified XHR response minus js:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="ngApp" id="ng-app" ng-class="viewName">
    <body ng-controller="AppController">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="maincontent" tabindex="-1">
            <div ng-view autoscroll="true" data-ng-animate="{{viewAnimation}}"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've spent days reviewing these pages - can't figure it out, AngularJS is foreign to me.  Can't get $compile to work, property of invoke undefined, and other hair pulling.  I'm lost.

- [AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)
- [AngularJS not working with JQuery displayed html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394378/angularjs-not-working-with-jquery-displayed-html)
- [Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)
- [AngularJS: Insert HTML from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761724/angularjs-insert-html-from-a-string)
- [Compile angular controller inserted by javascript dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672948/compile-angular-controller-inserted-by-javascript-dynamically)

Is there a way to have a chrome extension process the XHR return to capture the remaining dynamic code?

Comment: You can try adding an iframe in the background page DOM for the remote site and [strip its X-Frame-Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension), then extract the processed html in onload + timeout or MutationObserver to catch the moment when DOM was dynamically updated by the page script.

Comment: I was able to load the iframe I think in the background, but I'm running into cross-origin issues trying to read the DOM.

Comment: Add the URL you need to access to "permissions" key in manifest, see the docs for an example. Or `<all_urls>`.

Comment: Already had, permissions don't appear to work for iframe.  According to a comment on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724135/creating-a-hidden-iframe-in-a-chrome-extension permission "only applies to cross-origin XMLHttpRequests, injecting content scripts, and reading cookies. It does not apply to reading an iframe within a background page."  Looking at maybe trying a content script in the iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248467/chrome-extension-accessing-a-cross-origin-iframe-within-background-html